# Unable to run official drupal 7.59-fpm image

Tags: docker, drupal-7

I run the command `docker run --name some-drupal -p 9000:9000 -d drupal:7.59-fpm` but I see an empty website when I run http://127.0.0.1:9000/. whereas running `docker run --name some-drupal1 -p 8080:80 -d drupal` works. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with fpm. Just pay attention to nginx config (it's at host machine in my case).

I added this line to config:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
```